# Twig - add all days between two dates to an array

Tags: arrays, date, for-loop, twig

I need to solve how to add all days that are between two dates in twig.

Current code:

```
{% set dates = [] %}

{% for event in events %}
    {% set dates = dates|merge([event.date_start, event.date_end]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected output - an Array with all dates that are between event.date_start and event.date_end.

Comment: Why don't you solve this in your controller?

Comment: Because I'm not skilled in php. My focus is on front-end so I'm trying to solve this in a twig template.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to do this in twig you'd need to calculate the difference between the start and end date and populate the array with an extra loop

```html
{% for event in events %}
    {{ event.title }}
    
    {% set dates = [] %}
    {% set diff = date(event.end_date).diff(date(event.start_date)) %}
    
    {% set start = date(event.start_date) %}
    
    {% for i in 0..diff.days %}
        {% set dates = dates|merge([ start, ]) %}
        
        {% set start = start|date_modify('+ 1 day') %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% for date in dates %}
        {{ date|date('d-m-Y') }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/2uo6iq)

Comment: Thank you for the solution!